# Mock a go-logr and verify the message it logs?

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection, interface, mocking

Im using the following [`go-logr/logr`](https://github.com/go-logr/logr) library.
I have a test which needs to pass the `logger as parameter` and check that it was able to **log the data** that was sent.

I need to test the function `GetConfig`:

```
config, err := GetConfig(FilePath, "ns", logger, "test" )
```

At the end I need to print some message from the logger in the test

```
Expect(logger.msg).To(Equal("test"))
```

**My question is how should mock it?**

I’ve tried with the following but without success

```
func NewTestLogger() logr.Logger {
    l := &testlogger{
        Formatter: funcr.NewFormatter(funcr.Options{}),
    }
    return logr.New(l)
}


var _ = Describe(“test” action, func() {
    It("action configuration with  logger", func() {

        //var t *testing.T
        tl := NewTestLogger()
        config, err := GetConfig(kcfgFilePath, "ns", tl, "test")
```

But Im not able to print the value from the logger, how can I do it right?

```
Something like
```

`assert.Contains(t, tl.sink.Output, "test")`

Should I use the testing package?
**update**

This is a working version **without** the assertion.
Not sure what I miss there as I want to assert the data that are coming from the output of the `GetConfig`   'tl` and get the key and value

**This is close to the code I've in prod, how can I make work?**
https://go.dev/play/p/XDDkNjkESUw

**My Question is how should I assert the following**

```
assert.Contains(t, tl.GetSink().WithName("Output"), "test") 
assert.Contains(t, tl.GetSink().WithName("Output"), "message") 
assert.Contains(t, tl.GetSink().WithName("Output"), "print something")
```

**I was able to get the data like following, but not sure how to assert the values**

Comment: You can do the same as ChaosMonkey mentioned, try `assert.Contains(t, tl.GetSink().WithName("Output").Output, "test")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logr.New` function accepts any implementation of the [LogSink interface](https://github.com/go-logr/logr/blob/28755ae811e8511239e62a7b90b5ca808b691fca/logr.go#L416) - This means you should just implement one that saves the calls onto a slice in-memory instead of printing, and then you can expect that the slice has your log output.

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    // ... some extra imports
)

type TestLogger struct {
    Output map[string]map[int][]interface{}
    r RuntimeInfo
}
func (t *TestLogger) doLog(level int, msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) {
    m := make(map[int][]interface{}, len(keysAndValues))
    m[level] = keysAndValues
    t.output[msg] = m
}
func (t *TestLogger) Init(info RuntimeInfo) { t.r = info}
func (t *TestLogger) Enabled(level int) bool {return true}
func (t *TestLogger) Info(level int, msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) { t.doLog(level, msg, keysAndValues...) }
func (t *TestLogger) Error(err error, msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) { t.doLog(level, msg, append(keysAndValues, err)...) }
func (t *TestLogger) WithValues(keysAndValues ...interface{}) LogSink { return t}
func (t *TestLogger) WithName(name string) LogSink { return t }


func TestLoggerHasOutput(t *testing.T) {

        l := &TestLogger{make(map[string]map[int][]interface[]), RuntimeInfo{1}}
        tl := logr.New(l)
        config, err := GetConfig(kcfgFilePath, "ns", tl, "test")
        assert.Contains(t, l.Output, "ns") // you can also test the contents of the output as well
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 1+ I miss only the `GetConfig` with your variation, how would you simple do that to compere that input and the output to see that the value are matched ?

Comment: I tried with `func GetConfig(log logr.Logger, val string) (logr.Logger, error) {
 log.Info(val)
 return log, nil
}` which doesnt works any idea?

Comment: Please see my question update